# JFrame not displaying camera feed when trying to scan in QR code, and the exit button isn't working

Tags: java, qr-code

Warning: Beginner, may not understand certain concepts.

I was coding a QR code scanner, and I was trying to make a popup JFrame window that displays a video feed of the webcam. The issue is that when the window pops up, it displays a blank white screen. The scanner itself works, but the video feed isn't showing up.

I tried changing the background color, and the background color didn't change. I tried setting the JFrame to be undecorated, and the entire frame disappeared. I found this to be quite odd.

Using package com.github.sarxos

Found another snippet of code that works on its own, but doesn't work in my program. I coded this program quite terribly, so I won't be pasting the verbose code. The only thing that I used was 4 action listeners for buttons and keys. Could this be the issue?

Here is it calling upon the function.

```java
confirmButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // gets all the necessary info from the screen before going to next screen
                event = eventName.getText();
                // String monthString = monthDropdown.getText();

                // get dropdown stuff here

                // send info to server here

                // hides the first screen
                firstScreen.setVisible(false);
                firstScreen.dispose();
                // advances to second screen
                secondScreen();
            }
        });
```

Here is the function:

```java
 public void secondScreen() {
        // set up second screen here
        JFrame secondScreen = new JFrame();
        secondScreen.setLayout(null);
        // secondScreen.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        fullScreen(secondScreen);

        // gets rid of the header
        // secondScreen.setUndecorated(true);

        // sets the background to dark gray
        secondScreen.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        // disables alt-f4
        // secondScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        scanQRCode scanner = new scanQRCode();
        Future<String> scannedQRCode = scanner.getQRCode(secondScreen, (int) dimensions.getWidth(),
                (int) dimensions.getHeight());

        JButton alternativeLoginButton = new JButton("Or Login with Student ID");
        alternativeLoginButton.setBounds((int) (0.5 * dimensions.getWidth() - 100),
                (int) (0.8 * dimensions.getHeight()), 200, 25);
        alternativeLoginButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        alternativeLoginButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        // manual thingy
        alternativeLoginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                manualStudentId(secondScreen);
            }
        });

        secondScreen.add(alternativeLoginButton);

        secondScreen.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        secondScreen.setVisible(true);

        try {
            String QRCode_Value = scannedQRCode.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in getting QRCode value");
            // probably shouldn't ever get here????
        }
    }
```

And here is the QR Code Scanner:

````java
public class scanQRCode {
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

    // puts the QR code in the middle of the screen
    public Future<String> getQRCode(JFrame frame, int width, int height) {
        Callable<String> scanTask = () -> {
            Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault(); // Generate Webcam Object
            webcam.setViewSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
            WebcamPanel webcamPanel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
            webcamPanel.setMirrored(false);
            webcamPanel.setBounds((int) (width / 2) - 320, (int) (height / 2) - 240, 640, 480);
            frame.add(webcamPanel);
            // jFrame.setVisible(true);

            // jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            // @Override
            // public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            // // the window is minimized, terminate the task here
            // jFrame.dispose();
            // }
            // });

            // jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            // public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            // webcam.close();
            // }
            // });
            do {
                try {
                    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
                    System.out.println(image);
                    if (image == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
                    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
                    Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
                    if (result.getText() != null) {
                        jFrame.setVisible(false);
                        jFrame.dispose();
                        webcam.close();
                        return result.getText();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } while (true);
        };
        return executor.submit(scanTask);
    } // End of scanQRCode

// other code

}```
````

Comment: `while (webcam.isOpen()) {` looks suspious as it could be block the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: This seems like a prime candidate for a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Why did you remove the code? We can only help with some concrete code that shows what you are trying.

Comment: I added some additional info.